# how to pass html table data to controller in mvc2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a HTML table (grid). I want to pass the html table data to controller.(mvc 2.0)
can anyone help how does it is possible.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use jQuery to get all the rows and cells and then put the content of those cells into JSON object which could be posted to Action method.

Answer (score 0):

can you not just pass the innerHtml from a div which has the table html as a httpPost to a controller and get it as a string argument, you may have issues with string lengths using this method.

but i dont understand your logic of why you would want to do that, are you trying to persist data?

Comment: I wanted to save the gird data to database through Controller->applicationservices.

Comment: I would use Jakubs idea or maybe pass the data as json to the view and use jquery to bind it to the grid, you can then pick it back up on postback from the grid datasource.